# Potential data type issue, sql between positive and negative values

Tags: php, mysql

Right, I asked a similar question before but I think I may have a better idea of the issue and should be able to write the question much better.

So here is the situation, I have worked out roughly 20 miles in lat a long around a start point. I am searching the database for this amount either side of the start lat and start long. Once I get the results I will put them through a different function to check the exact distance and continue on.

So here is some data, this is what I will query.

```
$lat1 = 55.02
$lat2 = 53.04
$long1 = 1.04
$long2 = -0.43
```

The query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (LatCo BETWEEN :lat1 AND :lat2) AND (LongCo BETWEEN :long1 AND :long2)
```

I bind the variables the standard PDO way.

```
$stmt->bindParam(":lat1", $lat1);
$stmt->bindParam(":lat2", $lat2);
$stmt->bindParam(":long1", $long1);
$stmt->bindParam(":long2", $long2);
```

Some example data from my table and expected outcome:

```
Name  |  Lat  | Long  | Current Outcome
PL1   |54.023 |0.53   | Correct, pulls record
PL2   |58.125 |1.64   | Correct, does not pull record
PL3   |53.875 |-0.46  | Incorrect, pulls record
```

So I did some quick testing an for PL3, it appears that it pulls it where Long is = or higher than -0.46, but should it be -0.47 it would not pull the record even though thats when it should.

I think this could potentially be a datatype issue in the table, at the moment its set to `varchar`

Comment: `between` is a shorthand for `>= AND <=`. It seems that you're binding the values in the wrong order. The first value should be the lesser one (`53.04` for lat and `-0,43` for long) and the last value should be the higher one (`55.02` for lat and `1.04` for long). But it doesn't explain the problem itself.

Comment: Although my example isn't great, I do check that they are in order to prevent that from happening